# best way to Async or background call remain alive in activities

Tags: java, android

I am making a method that uses a third-party library which uses a card reader, I use an asynchronous call to do the reading, but the library does not have a method that tells me if the card was removed from the slot, but it does tell me a method if it is in the slot. For this I use a constant reading and through a variable I determine if it was removed from the reader.

For them I use an async method, which starts in the reading process, my problem is that when doing the reading, another 3 activities are opened in cascade and I require that the reading process remains active until the end of three activities later.

My question is what is the best practice to do that reading or what do you recommend making it the most efficient?

Best regards.

PD: I do very research, but in the debug the app become very slow. for this my question for the best practice or method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something else. I was also having issue like this.

```java
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
         //enter code here
    }).start();
```

I hope this way you won't that issue